# How to close a pyglet window?

Tags: python, pyglet

I have a following problem.
Suppose I have a following code:

```
@window.event
def on_key_press( symbol, mod):
    if condition == True:
       return print("Game over")

pyglet.app.run()
```

I need to also to close the window after the condition == True is met. How can I do that please?
I tried:

```
@window.event
def on_key_press( symbol, mod):
    if condition == True:
       return print("Game over")
       pyglet.app.exit()
```

but it did not work. Thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is terminated at the the first occurrence of `return` in the control flow. You have to remove the `return` statement.

```py
@window.event
def on_key_press( symbol, mod):
    if condition == True:

       # return print("Game over") <--- DELETE
       
       print("Game over")

       pyglet.app.exit()
```